# Отсутствует пункт "Добавить таблицу" в контекстном меню

Tags: sql-server

Создал в Visual Studio базу данных, пытаюсь добавить таблицу, нажав правой кнопкой по папке "Таблицы", но там отсутствует пункт "Добавить таблицу", только "Обновить" и "Свойства". Нашел такую же проблему тут https://toster.ru/q/184349

Но там решение для 15-ой студии, у меня 13-я. Но в тоже время, когда я работаю с БД через Management Studio никаких проблем нету. Подскажите, что делаю не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не установлен компонент [sql server data tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dn864412)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно установить прямо из Visual Studio:

**Tools -> Extensions and updates -> Updates**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В ручника установил - работает. Спасибо!